# Can I have multiple folders like webapps and specify what domains to access which ROOT.war file

Tags: java, tomcat, server.xml

I am using apache apache-tomcat-8.5.6 for deploying my web applications. I have a webapps folder and a ROOT.war file under webapps and all my domains by default access this ROOT.war file.
Now I am planning to add two more folders similar to webapps, let's say folder1 and folder2 and planning to deploy ROOT.war under both these folders. 
Now I want a certain domain to access ROOT.war under folder1 and another to access folder2. All other domains by default should access ROOT.war under webapps.

I believe that this is possible and might need some changes under the server.xml file. I am new to server configurations. Is there any good documentations or su

Answer (score 1):

This is absolutely possible.

The key of this solution is that the Engine-Tag attribute "defaultHost" names the application-Host which is used by default and the Host-Tag attribute "name" contains the domain name which uses this application if it matches.

Example server.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

    <GlobalNamingResources>
        <Resource
            auth="Container"
            description="Database that can be updated and saved"
            factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
            name="UserDatabase" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml"
            type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase" />
    </GlobalNamingResources>

    <Service name="Catalina">
        <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443" useBodyEncodingForURI="true" />

        <Engine defaultHost="defaultHost" name="Catalina">
            <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase" />
            <Host
                name="defaultHost"
                appBase="webapps-leave-empty">

                <Valve
                    className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
                    directory="${catalina.base}/logs/access/"
                    rotatable="true"
                    buffered="true"
                    prefix=""
                    suffix="-access.log"
                    fileDateFormat="yyyyMMdd"
                    pattern='%a %t %v "%r" %s %b "%{Referer}i" "%{User-Agent}i" %I' />
                <Context docBase="<PathToDefaultApplication>" path="" />
            </Host>

            <Host
                name="<SpecialDomain1>"
                appBase="webapps-leave-empty">

                <Valve
                    className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
                    directory="${catalina.base}/logs/access/"
                    rotatable="true"
                    buffered="true"
                    prefix=""
                    suffix="-access.log"
                    fileDateFormat="yyyyMMdd"
                    pattern='%a %t %v "%r" %s %b "%{Referer}i" "%{User-Agent}i" %I' />
                <Context docBase="<PathToApplication1>" path="" />
            </Host>

            <Host
                name="<SpecialDomain2>"
                appBase="webapps-leave-empty">

                <Valve
                    className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
                    directory="${catalina.base}/logs/access/"
                    rotatable="true"
                    buffered="true"
                    prefix=""
                    suffix="-access.log"
                    fileDateFormat="yyyyMMdd"
                    pattern='%a %t %v "%r" %s %b "%{Referer}i" "%{User-Agent}i" %I' />
                <Context docBase="<PathToApplication2>" path="" />
            </Host>
        </Engine>
    </Service>
</Server>
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. Is there any way I can include those extra host entries from an external file in the conf folder. I am looking for a wildcard so that all files of that pattern gets included automatically.